# How to color a particular node in angular-treeview control

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular.treeview plugin for displaying a tree structure.

Could somebody please help me in how to get the handle of a node in the tree and applying some custom class to it .

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I will paste a few poignant parts downloaded from the GIThub usage instructions. The full html file is attached

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular.treeview.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/angular.treeview.css">
    <script>
        (function () {
            //angular module
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularTreeview']);
            //test controller
            myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
                //test tree model 1

                $scope.roleList1 = [
                    { "roleName": "User", "roleId": "role1", "children": [
                        { "roleName": "subUser1", "roleId": "role11", "children": [] },
                        { "roleName": "subUser2", "roleId": "role12", "children": [
                            { "roleName": "subUser2-1", "roleId": "role121", "children": [
                                                        . . . 
                ];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="TREE MODEL 1" data-ng-click="roleList = roleList1"/>
            <input type="button" value="TREE MODEL 2" data-ng-click="roleList = roleList2"/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin:10px 0 30px 0; padding:10px; background-color:#EEEEEE; border-radius:5px; font:12px Tahoma;">
            <span><b>Selected Node</b> : {{currentNode.roleName}}</span>
        </div>
        <div
                data-angular-treeview="true"
                data-tree-model="roleList"
                data-node-id="roleId"
                data-node-label="roleName"
                data-node-children="children">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: For more help you must visit these link: 
http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/

https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview#usage

Comment: The person who has given a down vote, I request you to represent a better suggestion then voting people down to achieve Badges.

Comment: Hi @dreamyourcareer , i am not trying to color a selected node. My requirement is to show that node colored , for which i have loaded the heirachy. So basically i somehow need to compare each node id with the  passed in id and color that node , on load of the tree. Is there any way?